# How to calculate $E[X]$ of a Poisson random variable.

Tags: probability

I'm studying probability and I came across this segment in the notes I got. [image]

It describes a type of random variable called "Poisson random variable" and it's main characteristics are that $Im(X) = \{0,1,2,3,...\} = \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ with $X$ being a given random variable and

[image]

where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R^+}$  (any real number above 0).

What I don't understand is inside the calculation of $E[X]$, which is normally defined as:

[image]

we see these last few steps:

[image]

I understand how we can get from the first step here to the second, However how do we get to $\lambda$. Why can we just remove the entire summation and $e^{-\lambda}$ here?

Comment: Look at the taylor series of exp. That infinite sum is just $e^λ$ in disguise.

Comment: *aleatoria* $\equiv$ *random*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum is nothing but $e^{\lambda}$. Also $e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda}=1$.

Comment: ok, This information is new to me, could you maybe elaborate why this is?

Comment: You know the probabilities sum to $1$ so $1=\sum\limits_{k\ge 0} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda} = e^{-\lambda} \sum\limits_{k\ge 0} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} $  and so $e^{\lambda} = \sum\limits_{k\ge 0} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} $